# Cannot import spreadsheet

Tags: 2013, spreadsheet

When I try to import a spreassheet and clicked import after typed the Title, It says

> Your browser should support ActiveX for the import operation.

I couldn't understand what here written. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15995.import-excel-sheet-as-sharepoint-list.aspx

What should I do for it? Thank you.

Comment: Can you also try this [reference](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_manage/unable-to-import-a-spreadsheet-into-a-site/73a34bcd-8e37-429e-83a0-91b85f59bde9?auth=1)?

Answer (score 0):

Well have you tried to enable ActiveX in your browser?

If you use IE: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help/genuine/ie-activex

Comment: The options are like what written in page. When I click import now, it says "Could not load an object because it is not available on this machine"

Comment: Is the site in your local intranet or in the trusted sites?

Comment: Local intranet.

Comment: When I click ok for that message, it opens excel in Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications and a message prompt. I says"Compile error: The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems. Please review and update Declare statements and tgen mark them with PtrSafe attribute."Here is a screenshot http://compfreek.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/capture1.png

Comment: Hmm... are you opening it with a 64bit version IE? Maybe try the 32bit version.

Comment: Try that one ;) Maybe it works:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c516255a-bb6d-4812-836d-7be23705394c/error-when-importing-excel-2007-spreadsheet-into-sharepoint-2010-using-import-spreadsheet

Comment: My IE is 10 :/ I did the same options with Google Chrome too but didnt work.

Comment: I add the site to the trusted sites but didnt work. I looked this link. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/375fb173-afdf-4b0e-86d2-bf687f06f436/unable-to-import-from-spreadsheet .But my office is 2013. What should I do more?

Answer (score 0):

The linked article in your link was listed as not found - so I am outlining the two ways that I am aware of to import spreadsheet data to Sharepoint without code.

The first is to use the out-of-the-box import spreadsheet app part. If you encounter errors during this approach, we will need more information to determine what the problem may be. I do not anticipate an ActiveX error based on this approach, and without being able to review the linked article, it will be hard to tell what the issue may be if you did encounter an ActiveX error while doing so.

The second option is to utilize the super unstable ActiveX plugins that Sharepoint 2013 offers. You need to use Internet Explorer 32 bit for this option. What you do is you essentially a copy and paste (Ctrl+C in MS Excel, then go to sharepoint via IE and select the first cell on a new line while on the "Quick Edit" view on the list, the do a Ctrl+V). It is not recommended to do more than 50 rows of edit at at time using this approach, as it may crash the script.

Hope this is helpful!